# SharePoint Designer - Workflow update list value from another list

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, designer

I've scoured the web and can't find a tutorial or steps to accomplish the following.  I want to create a workflow that detects that the date column named "Release" has changed in list 1 and updates another date column but named "Launched" in another list 2.  The record in list 1 and list 2 both have a column named "AccountID" where the value of AccountID is the same in both lists.  Can you point me to some high level steps, tutorial, etc. for me to accomplish this?  I'm using SharePoint Designer 2013.  Appreciate any help you can provide.  To contribute to the community, I'll leverage your responses and make a video tutorial and post it back here.  Thank you all.

**Detailed Example**

Originally, list 2 has date column named "Launch" = 1/1/2017 I will change date column named "Release" in list 1 from 1/1/2017 to 2/2/2017 I want the workflow to detect the change in list 1 and update the corresponding record in list 2 Note that list 1 and list 2 both have a column named "AccountID".  In my example, the list 1 record with value 1/1/2017 and the list 2 record with new/changed value of 2/2/2017 both have the value "BINGFOOT" in the Account ID column

Comment: here is a nice example that will help you.have a look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/210353ac-d383-417a-9840-235953f962cb/how-do-i-update-on-field-on-second-list-using-sharepoint-designer?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Comment: Thank you.  Here's how I leveraged your suggestions.. 

Step 1
=====
Wait for DateField1 to be greater than 1/1/1900
then email myself
then set variable:ItemID to CurrentItem:ItemID
then set variable:ItemDate to CurrentTiem:ItemDate

Step 2
======
Update ItemID in List#2
...where list #2 required that we find the list itemID with item = variable:itemID

What would be really cool is to put an IF clause that says "IF and only IF the variable is found, then proceed with the update".  Is that possible?  And where do I check where workflows may have failed?